# Factory girl seems to be creating more than one object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Hi I am using factory girl to test my project but one thing I keep coming up against is factory girl keeps creating more than one object for example I have the following test:-

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 feature 'Category' do


scenario "creation" do
    @category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
    visit new_admin_category_path
    fill_in "category_category_name", :with => "trousers"
    page.select('Foo', :from => "category_products_products")
    click_button('Save Category')
end

scenario "editing" do
    @category = FactoryGirl.create(:category, :products_attributes => [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product, :name => "Barz")])
    visit edit_admin_category_path(@category.slug)
    fill_in "category_category_name", :with => "Baz"
    page.select('Barz', :from => "category_products_products")
    click_button("Save Category")
    page.driver.submit '/admin/products/#{@category.slug}', :category_name => @category.category_name, :products_attributes => @category.products_attributes
end

scenario "denied entry when not logged in" do
    visit admin_index_path
    page.should  have_content("Please log in")
    visit new_session_path
end
end
```

My Factories are as follows:-
    require 'factory_girl'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
  category_name "Trousers"
  slug "trousers"
  department
  products_attributes { [ FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product) ]}
end

factory :user do
 username "Foo"
 password "Bar"
end

factory :product do
  name "Foo"
  price 9999
  description "I am a foobar"
  slug "foo"
  category
  department
end

factory :department do
  department_name "Mens"
  slug "mens"
  products_attributes { [ FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product) ]}
end
end
```

I get the following error:-

```
2) Category creation
Failure/Error: page.select('Foo', :from => "category_products_products")
 Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching option "Foo"
 # ./spec/features/category_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What could I be doing wrong in my code?

Here's my spec_helper:-

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'rack/test'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true
  config.order = "random"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

 config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end

 config.include Capybara::DSL

end
```

HTML generated:-

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label">
         <label for="category_category_name">Category name</label>
     </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="category_category_name" name="category[category_name]" size="30"  type="text" />
    </div>
        </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">
      <label for="category_products_products">Products</label>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select>
    <select id="category_products_products" name="category[products][products]"><option value="56">Foo</option>
<option value="57">Foo</option></select>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class"control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <button class="btn">
     <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save Category" />
    </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Category model:-

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId 
    friendly_id :category_name, use: :slugged
  attr_accessible :category_name, :products_attributes, :slug

  has_many :products
  belongs_to :department

  validates_presence_of :category_name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products

end
```

view code:-

```
<%= form_for :category do  |f| %>
    <div class="category-form-new">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    <%= f.label :category_name %>
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :category_name %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.fields_for :products do |product_form| %>
                <label class="control-label">
                    <%= product_form.label :products, "Products" %>
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select>
                        <%= product_form.select :products, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :name) %>
                    </select>
            <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class"control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button class="btn">
                        <%= f.submit %>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Capybara is referring to two HTML elements on your page and that this has nothing to do with FactoryGirl.

Comment: Foo is the product objects name it appears its been created twice as there are two within the select box element.

Comment: Can you share the HTML generated? Is the user displayed in that section as well by any chance? I noticed your factory generates a user name of `Foo` also. 

It doesn't make sense that FactoryGirl would generate two objects with a single create. You didn't turn off transactional mode, did you?

Comment: Did you check that the test database is empty when you start your test?

Comment: I use database cleaner I have attached my spec_helper and the html generated.

Comment: Sorry for some of the not-so-smart comments/questions so far. ;-) Would you mind sharing your Category model?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see anything wrong and I'm reluctant to keep asking for "one more thing". I'm inclined to just delete my answer at this point, but if there was one more thing I'd want to look at, it's the .erb files contributing to your HTML for this page.

Comment: I have added the erb files of the view in question